# Extracting a specific word and a number of tokens on each side of it from each string in a column in SAS?

Tags: string, sas, token

Extracting a specific word and a number of tokens on each side of it from each string in a column in SAS EG ?

For example,

```
row1: the sun is nice
row2: the sun looks great
row3: the sun left me
```

Is there a code that would produce the following result column (2 words where sun is the first):

```
SUN IS 
SUN LOOKS
SUN LEFT
```

and possibly a second column with COUNT in case of duplicate matches.

So if there was 20 SUN LOOKS then it they would be grouped and have a count of 20.

Thanks

Comment: Please post what you've tried.  You can probably use the SCAN() function but it depends a little on your data.

Comment: Or split the sentence so that you have each word on a separate line, with a variable to indicate the sentence and one to indicate the nth word.  Basically n-grams where n=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use functions `findw()` and `scan()` to do want you want. Both of those functions operate on the concept of word boundaries. `findw()` returns the position of the word in the string. Once you know the position, you can use `scan()` in a loop to get the next word or words following it.

Here is a simple example to show you the concept. It is by no means a finished or polished solution, but intended you point you in the right direction. The input data set (text) contains the sentences you provided in your question with slight modifications. The data step finds the word "sun" in the sentence and creates a variable named fragment that contains 3 words ("sun" + the next 2 words).

```
data text2;
set text;
length fragment $15;
word = 'sun'; * search term;
fragment_len = 3; * number of words in target output;

word_pos = findw(sentence, word, ' ', 'e');
if word_pos then do;
    do i = 0 to fragmen_len-1;
        fragment = catx(' ', fragment, scan(sentence, word_pos+i));
    end;
end;
run;
```

Here is a partial print of the output data set.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help! great example you have put me in the right dierction.

Comment: You're welcome. If I helped you solve your problem, I would appreciate an upvote or check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the `INDEX`, `SUBSTR` and `SCAN` functions to achieve this functionality.

`INDEX` - takes two arguments and returns the position at which a given substring appears in a string. You might use:

`INDEX(str,'sun')`

`SUBSTR` - simply returns a substring of the provided string, taking a second numeric argument referring to the starting position of the substring. Combine this with your `INDEX` function:

`SUBSTR(str,INDEX(str,'sun'))`

This returns the substring of `str` from the point where the word `'sun'` first appears.

`SCAN` - returns the 'words' from a string, taking the string as the first argument, followed by a number referring to the 'word'. There is also a third argument that specifies the delimiter, but this defaults to space, so you wouldn't need it in your example.

To pick out the word after `'sun'` you might do this:

`SCAN(SUBSTR(str,INDEX(str,'sun')),2)`

Now all that's left to do is build a new string containing the words of interest. That can be achieved with concatenation operators. To see how to concatenate two strings, run this illustrative example:

```
data _NULL_;
  a = 'Hello';
  b = 'World';
  c = a||' - '||b;
  put c;
run;
```

The log should contain this line:

```
Hello - World
```

As a result of displaying the value of the `c` variable using the `put` statement. There are a number of functions that can be used to concatenate strings, look in the documentation at `CAT`,`CATX`,`CATS` for some examples.

Hopefully there is enough here to help you.